# error: ‘selectROI’ is not a member of ‘cv’

Tags: c++, opencv

I use Ubuntu 18.04 and opencv3.4.0(with 3.3.1contrib), when i try to compile my project, these errors occured:

```
/home/sunyq/SiamMaskCpp/demo.cpp:98:24: error: ‘selectROI’ is not a member of ‘cv’
 cv::Rect roi = cv::selectROI("SiamMask", images.front(), false);
                    ^~~~~~~~~
/home/sunyq/SiamMaskCpp/demo.cpp:98:24: note: suggested alternative: ‘DetectionROI’
 cv::Rect roi = cv::selectROI("SiamMask", images.front(), false);
                    ^~~~~~~~~
                    DetectionROI
/home/sunyq/SiamMaskCpp/demo.cpp:100:12: error: ‘cv::Rect {aka class cv::Rect_<int>}’ has no member named ‘empty’
 if(roi.empty())
        ^~~~~
CMakeFiles/demo.dir/build.make:81: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/demo.dir/demo.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/demo.dir/demo.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:94: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/demo.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/demo.dir/all] Error 2
```

here's my code and include files:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv/cv.hpp>


cv::namedWindow("SiamMask");
int64 toc = 0;
cv::Rect roi = cv::selectROI("SiamMask", images.front(), false);

if(roi.empty())
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

Is it that I didn't get the right version of opencv or something else?

Comment: `selectROI` is part of tracking API, so be sure to  `#include <opencv2/tracking.hpp>`

Comment: thank you, I modified CMakeList and specified opencv path and get it right. But another error occured:

Comment: [ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/demo.dir/demo.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable demo
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lCUDA_cublas_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/demo.dir/build.make:124: recipe for target 'demo' failed
make[2]: *** [demo] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:94: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/demo.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/demo.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:102: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2